# Halachically at what time is a baby born?

Tags: halacha, pregnancy-birth

Is a baby born when the head emerges, when the whole body emerges, when the cord is cut, or something else? This is relevant, for example, in order to determine the baby's birthday or when to do a bris for boys.

Comment: head https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%91_%D7%93

Comment: Niddah 28a mishna

Comment: Wow, what an interesting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to Double AA who referenced Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 262:4 ([Wikitext](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%91_%D7%93)).

[Sefaria text](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.262.4?lang=bi&with=Be%27er%20HaGolah&lang2=en):

נולד בין השמשות מונים לו מהלילה ונימול לתשיעי שהוא ספק שמיני ואם הוציא ראשו חוץ לפרוזדור מבעוד יום או ששמעו אותו בוכה אפילו נולד אחר כמה ימים מונה לו ח' ימים מיום שיצא ראשו או מיום ששמעו אותו בוכה: הגה וי"א דוקא בסתם אבל אם אמו אומרת דהתינוק היה מונח בבטנה כמו בשאר פעמים ולא היה לה חבלי לידה כלל אע"פ ששמעו בוכה מונין לו מיום הלידה דאע"ג דלא שכיח שיבכה בלא הוצאת הראש חוץ לפרוזדור מ"מ האם נאמנת לומר שהיה מונח כמו בשאר פעמים ובכה (בא"ז בשם תשו' ר' יואל הלוי והוא במהרי"ו סי' כ"ה):

ד If he was born during twilight he is circumcised on the ninth day because of doubt when the eigth day is. And if the head was out of the vagina while it was still day or a cry from it even if it was born after many days we count eight days from the day that the head came out or the time the cry from it was heard (There are those who say it in the plain case but if his mother says the baby was resting with the claim like most time and his nose was not yet born the general rule that even though we heard the cry from him while it was still day and even though babies don't cry until their head is outside of the vagina the mother is believed the rest of the time when she says the baby cried( rabbi Yoel haLevi))